# SIP Sorcery (C#) : How the server can reject call & Receiver can detect that server has rejected a call

Tags: c#, .net, asterisk, sip, sip-server

```
 SIPUserAgent objSIPUserAgent = new SIPUserAgent();
 WindowsAudioEndPoint objWindowsAudioEndPoint = new WindowsAudioEndPoint(new AudioEncoder());
 VoIPMediaSession objVoIPMediaSession = new VoIPMediaSession(objWindowsAudioEndPoint.ToMediaEndPoints());
 objVoIPMediaSession.AcceptRtpFromAny = true;

 string strDestinationAddress = strDialledNumber + gblStrDomain;
 bool blnCallResult = await objSIPUserAgent.Call(strDestinationAddress, gblStrExtentionNumber, gblStrExtentionPassword, objVoIPMediaSession);
```

- Server is calling to the reciver by using above snippet.
- Receiver notified with incoming call

I have two questions in this scenario.

1. How the server can reject/cancel outgoing call?
2. How receiver can detect that the call is rejected/cancelled by server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool result = objSIPUserAgent.HangUp();
```

This can be used to reject or cancel the outgoing call.

And Below, we can subscribe to the event OnCallRejected which gets fired the **call is rejected** by the server

```
objSIPUserAgent.OnCallRejected += (sender, args) => {
    
};
```

Also can OnCallTerminated event . This is fired when the **call is cancelled** by the server.

```
objSIPUserAgent.OnCallTerminated += (sender, args) => {
    if (args.Reason == CallTerminationReason.LocalCanceled) {
        // Handle call canceled event here
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.

OnCallRejected and OnCallTerminated events are not available in version 6.0.12 of the library. These events were added in a later version, specifically version 7.0.0

For older version,

```
objSIPUserAgent.CallHungup += (uas, reason, lastResponse) =>
{
    if (reason == SIPCallTerminateReasonsEnum.None)
    {
        // The call was terminated normally.
        Console.WriteLine("Call Terminated.");
    }
    else if (reason == 
          SIPCallTerminateReasonsEnum.RemoteCancel) {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled by remote party")
     }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I am using NUGet package of SIPSorcery (v.6.0.12). I am not getting events **OnCallRejected** & **OnCallTerminated**.

Comment: I think that the OnCallRejected and OnCallTerminated events are not available in version 6.0.12 of the library. These events were added in a later version, specifically version 7.0.0.

Comment: From where I can get latest version of SIPSorcery C# ? I have cloned an updated git repository, But it's still giving me a build of version 6.0.12. Also, I am not able to see a 7.0.0 version in NUGet package manager.

Comment: Could you try by opening the NuGet Package Manager settings and adding the following package source: https://www.myget.org/F/sipsorcery/api/v3/index.json.